# Nginx upstream_fair statistics

Tags: nginx

I am running nginx 1.0.6 as a load balancer and I am using the upstream_fair module. On its Nginx blog page (http://nginx.localdomain.pl/wiki/UpstreamFair), it mentioned that you can pull statistics from it.

What the page fails to mention is how to configure the stats page. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to patch nginx itself for that -- see http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2008-June/005839.html and related messages.  Not sure if these patches still apply cleanly to recent versions.